# How to print an expression ordered by a symbol in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I tried to use `init_printing(order=..)` but none of those orders match what i need.

For example:

```
exp=m*x**3 + 3*m**2*x + x**2 + 1

print(exp,x) will give:
m*x**3 + x**2 + 3*m**2*x + 1

print(exp,m) will give:
3*x*m**2 + 3*x**3*m + x**2 + 1
```

Comment: I have an expression `exp=m*x**3 + 3*m**2*x + x**2 + 1`; i want to make a `print()` function that `print(exp,x)` : print `exp` sorted by `x` give output `m*x**3 + x**2 + 3*m**2*x + 1`;
`print(exp,m)`: print `exp` sorted by `m` give output  : `3*x*m**2 + 3*x**3*m + x**2 + 1`